# How to remove In-App Purchases: Auto-Renewable Subscriptions from my iOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

If I have In-App purchases: Auto-Renewable Subscriptions in my app, but I want to discontinue this service (the app still usable), how can I do it? Would remove in-app from iTuneConnect/AppStoreConnect do the trick?

**Updated**
I have other in-app purchase options which I still want to continue, so turn off capabilities as @aBilal17 suggested isn't an option.

Comment: are you talking about in app purchase?

Comment: Just go to Target -> capabilities and Turn Off in-App purchases. And then check

Comment: @Lion Yes in-app purchase: auto-renewable subscription

Comment: @aBilal17 Let say I have other in-app which I still want to support.

Comment: remove that inapppurchase from itunes connect! that's it!

Comment: If you want in-app in one section and don't want on another section. Then just comment code from that section in which you want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, to discontinue an auto-renew subscription remove it from sale in iTune/AppStore connect. Customers will be notified about the discontinued subscription, but you need to provided service for the remaining duration of subscription period.

So if you have x-day subscription period, you should remove it x days before ending your service, so that all customers get content until the end.